# Is Visual C++ correct when it refuses this template-"dependent" based enum?

Tags: c++, c++11

Code:

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#    pragma warning( disable: 4480 )     // enum base as "nonstandard extension"
#endif
enum ShouldBeFine: char { hola };

enum Choice { a, b, c };

template< Choice c > struct Traits;

template<> struct Traits<a> { typedef char Type; };
template<> struct Traits<b> { typedef wchar_t Type; };
template<> struct Traits<c> { typedef long Type; };

template< Choice c >
struct Blah
{
    enum X: typename Traits<c>::Type {};
};

int main()
{}
```

Only after a [Herculean effort](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Herculean) to file a [bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/699236/visual-c-does-not-handle-typed-enums-correctly) with Microsoft, did it occur to me that maybe Visual C++ is correct to refuse it, and g++, which compiles the above fine, is maybe wrong?

**EDIT** Details: the code fails to compile with Visual C++ 10.0 and with the preview of Visual C++ 11.0. Those compilers spit out some rambling error avalanche beginning with an alleged syntax error. The code compiles fine with MinGW g++ 4.4.1. [Dani](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8018267/is-visual-c-correct-when-it-refuses-this-template-dependent-based-enum/8018282#8018282) reports that it compiles fine with CLang. Unfortunately Comeau Online does not support this language feature, so it can't be decided in the way we often did for C++98, just give the code to Comeau.

Comment: Is `ShouldBeFine` just there to illustrate that typed enums compile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am reading the grammar correctly, you are correct in that this should compile.  `enum-base` is `: type-specifier-seq`, and `type-specifier-seq` seems to include pretty much any type name you can think of, including `typename Traits<c>::Type`. And all three specializations result in `Type` being integral, which is also required of the enum-base.  So That looks kosher to me.

Comment: Strongly-typed enums are officially supported in the forthcoming Visual C++ 11 (not just partially supported).  See [C++11 Features in Visual C++ 11](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/09/12/10209291.aspx)

Comment: Huh, so it is.  That's one of the features I've been waiting for, so I'm surprised I overlooked that.

Comment: @AlfP.Steinbach: Yes, I tried it out.  I concur with Dennis's reading of the spec; this may well be a bug.  I don't see an obvious workaround either.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis: could you click on the "I can too" (the I can also reproduce it) button at the MS [bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/699236/visual-c-does-not-handle-typed-enums-correctly#details)?

Answer (score 0):

This compiles fine in both clang and g++. In addition, template substitution should occur before the class and the enum inside is created, so it should not matter if its template dependent or not.

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed in the Visual C++ 11 Beta, released on February 29, 2012.

Note also that the warning you disabled--C4480--has also been fixed, so it is no longer incorrectly emitted in native C++ code when `enum class` is used.